# TSC/Rollup: how to pipe TSC output into Rollup without TSC emitting files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rollupjs, tsc

I'm using rollup with TSC to generate es modules based bundle. When I run `npm run build` tsc transpiles `.ts` to `.js` files inside `src`. After that, Rollup takes the `.js` files and does some magic like turning `bare module imports` into `relative imports` to make it browser compatible and outputs it into `dist` folder.

Now the question is: **How can you "give" the output of TSC's `js` files to Rollup without emitting them to the src folder?**

I know about the `noEmit` tsconfig option but then I have no `js` files to give to Rollup.

I'm using TSC because Babel gave me problems with decorators.

This is the command:

[image]

This is the folder structure. As you can see inside `src` folder every `.ts` file has it `.js` file which is redundant and is clutter in the `src` folder. Would be nice to have them not saved there and just used as input for rollup.

[image]

**Rollup config**

```js
import html from "@web/rollup-plugin-html";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";

export default {
  input: "src/index.html",
  output: { dir: "dist", format: "es", preserveModules: true },
  plugins: [
    html(),
    nodeResolve(),
    copy({
      targets: [{ src: "src/manifest.json", dest: "dist" }],
    }),
  ],
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true /* Enable incremental compilation */,
    "target": "es2019" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "lib": [
      "ES2019",
      "DOM"
    ] /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */,
    "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */,
    "module": "ESNEXT" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "rootDirs": [
      "src"
    ] /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */,

    "importHelpers": true /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */,
    "noEmitOnError": true /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */,

    "isolatedModules": true /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */,
    "esModuleInterop": false /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

  
    "strict": true ,
    "skipLibCheck": true ,
    "pretty": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to output tsc emitted files into `tsc-out` folder inside the src folder and delete it after with pre- and post- npm scripts.